# How to prevent libvlc from opening a new window for every mp4 in playlist?

Tags: video, c, vlc

My requirement is that a list of mp4 files play sequentially in the same window. The aim is to produce a simple animated face, specific characteristics being added programmatically to the list. However, the only behavior I've been able to get out of vlc is that each file opens in a new window. A window opens, plays the first file, closes, a second window opens ... The code example exhibits this behavior for a sample of 3 files.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

I am running Raspian 10 and vlc media player 3.0.10

Thanks for looking at this!

---

```
libvlc_instance_t *vlcInstance;
libvlc_media_list_t *mList;
libvlc_media_list_player_t *mlp;
libvlc_media_t *md1, *md2, *md3;

vlcInstance = libvlc_new(0, NULL);

mList = libvlc_media_list_new(vlcInstance);

md1 = libvlc_media_new_path(vlcInstance, "/home/pi/video/leftwink.mp4");
md2 = libvlc_media_new_path(vlcInstance, "/home/pi/video/blink.mp4");
md3 = libvlc_media_new_path(vlcInstance, "/home/pi/video/cross.mp4");

libvlc_media_list_add_media(mList, md1);
libvlc_media_list_add_media(mList, md2);
libvlc_media_list_add_media(mList, md3);

libvlc_media_release(md1);
libvlc_media_release(md2);
libvlc_media_release(md3);

mlp = libvlc_media_list_player_new(vlcInstance);

libvlc_media_list_player_set_media_list(mlp, mList);

/* Play */
libvlc_media_list_player_play(mlp);
sleep(10);
```

---

Comment: Maybe using the same player with `libvlc_media_list_player_set_media_player(mlp, p_mp);` ? [Code example](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Media_List_Management/)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! When I add this function the behavior is identical to that without: vcl windows are opened and closed for each item on the playlist. Maybe I don't understand the p_mp argument in the _set_media_player function. I've declared it and set it via libvlc_media_player_new. It was not declared / set in the sample code.

Comment: Thanks again, I've found a different solution for this. Creating several media player instances and cycling through them works well for my needs. As each instance is played it appears on top of the previous instance (which can be released or, preferably, assigned a new media file and reused).

Comment: You're welcome. In the example code I can also read : `/* Get our media instance to use our window */ libvlc_media_player_set_drawable(mlp, window);` where window is type of `libvlc_drawable_t`. [Here](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/) you have window hook example.